# How I can open an external app from React Native in IOS if the app is installed go to an app other view and go to APP Store

Tags: javascript, ios

I want to open an external app from React Native in IOS if the app is installed go to an app other view and go to APP Store. I am done with that in Android using react-native-send-intent
works fine in Android but not working in ios.

```
const openExternalApp = item => {
    // console.log('item bank', item);
    if (Platform.OS == 'android') {
      if (item) {
        SendIntentAndroid.isAppInstalled(item.BundelID).then(suport => {
          if (suport) {
            SendIntentAndroid.openApp(item.BundelID);
          } else {
            Linking.canOpenURL(item.androidAppLink).then(suport => {
              if (suport) {
                Linking.openURL(item.androidAppLink);
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    } else {
      // console.log('ios');
      AppLink.maybeOpenURL(item?.ios?.url, {
        appName: item?.ios?.name,
        appStoreId: item?.ios?.appId,
        appStoreLocale: {appStoreId: item?.ios?.appId},
        // playStoreId,
      })
        .then(() => {
          // do stuff
        })
        .catch(err => {
          // handle error
        });
    }
  };
```